# Passing Parameters in omines/datatables

Tags: symfony, datatables

using Symfony 5 and Omines, I have 2 tables sending a request to the same url:

- the first table show products sold this month,
- the second table show products sold before this month

Therefore, I want to pass as a parameter a date. and then in the query_builder filter it.
I do not find any hint in the documentation.
Any help would be great.
Thanks,

Comment: Hi and welcome. I would like to point out that this question is missing of some crucial infos in order to understand what have you tried and what's the non working code. If you don't have any, please try to provide, for instance, a pseudo controller code, a pseudo repository (or query builder) code and so on. Without those details, is hard to produce something valuable for you and for the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

add your desired variable which you want to use in querybuilder like shown in example below

```
$table->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, [
        'entity' => Product::class,
        'query' => function (QueryBuilder $builder) use ($date) {
            $builder
                ->select('p')
                ->from(Product::class, 'p')
                ->where("p.date = :date")
                ->setParameter("date", $date)
            ;
        }, 
    ]);
```